# Find the expected number of stages until one of the players is eliminated.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

I have been given an example: 
[image]

Moreover I have been given a problem based on this example: [image]

I tried to find an appropriate martingale to solve this problem but I couldn't. I would appreciate any tips and hints.

Comment: The two player game is known to have an expected length that is the product of the starting numbers of coins.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have thought about $ M_n = X_n Y_n Z_n $, unfortunately it's not a martingale $ E(M_{n+1} | X_n = X, Y_n=Y, Z_n = Z) = XYZ -\frac{1}{3}(X + Y + Z) $.